# How to create moving background from right to left using CSS without using marquee?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a background in header, it should keep moving right to left continuously, picture should repeat itself. I don't want to use javascript here.

Comment: What is *header*? Also, what should be moving? The image? Or by that you mean the user will probably be scrolling through the "header"?

Comment: I just want to animate background in a loop.

Comment: **I found on stackoverflow** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503492/animate-marquee-image-in-css3 how it will work for you

Answer (score 3):

for this use css3 animations

they are very simple to use

```
.hi {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("http://files.simurai.com/misc/sprite.png");

    -webkit-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
       -moz-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
        -ms-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
         -o-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
            animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}


<img src="http://files.simurai.com/misc/sprite.png" />
<div class="hi"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/light/

Comment: Ya I know CSS3 can animate something but I don't know it will work in a loop or not.

Comment: @Hushme You should provide some code example. It'd make your answer much better. Your pointer is probably  in the right direction, but "use CSS3 animations" won't get the reader much further.

Comment: Thanks I also find it here 
http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/10/18/side-scrolling-parallax-background-effect-using-only-css3/