# Animate Marquee Image in CSS3

Tags: html, css, marquee

I'm trying to animate an image with CSS3, but I can't seem to get it right. I want the image to wrap around and infinantly scroll across the page, but I can't even get it to animate. 
My HTML is simple:

```
<div id="space" class="marquee">
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
    #space {
background-image:url(http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/bckgrnds/outrspc4.gif);
width:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
height:384px;
}
.marquee{
overflow: hidden;
     -webkit-animation: marquee 50s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
0%   { left:0 }
100% { left:100% }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9op2t9wa/

Comment: Have you tried adding `@-webkit-keyframes`? What browser version are you using? *Note:* This would not solve your wrap around problem but should get your animation working.

Comment: I changed it now, and the animation works! I'll do some more work at it to try to make it look like a never-ending loop of space. Another question though: Can you have a div animation start in one place, then restart in a different place? (i.e. it starts at left:0%, then when it reaches left:100%, it goes to left:-100%.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```css
#space {
  background-image: url(http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/bckgrnds/outrspc4.gif);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 384px;
}

.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: marquee 50s linear infinite;
  animation: marquee 50s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  from {
    left: 0
  }
  to {
    left: 100%
  }
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from {
    left: 0
  }
  to {
    left: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="space" class="marquee">
</div>
```

Comment: I changed it now, and the animation works! I'll do some more work at it to try to make it look like a never-ending loop of space. Another question though: Can you have a div animation start in one place, then restart in a different place? (i.e. it starts at left:0%, then when it reaches left:100%, it goes to left:-100%.)

Comment: If you want to do this, work with 2 backgrounds & 2 animations.
The first reach left:100% and the second start at left:-100%.

Answer (score 4):

Fairly simple, use the built-in default `repeat` of the `background-image`, and animate the `background-position` :

```css
.imageMarquee
{
    height: 180px; /* Any size you want */ 
    background-image:url(http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/bckgrnds/outrspc4.gif);
    animation: imageMovement 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes imageMovement {
    100% {
        background-position-x: 320px; /* width of the image */
    }        
}
```

```html
<div class="imageMarquee"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't currently work is that you are using -webkit-animation to animate, but are defining the keyframes without the -webkit- prefix.

To fix this, change `@keyframes` to `@-webkit-keyframes`.

Though, you should use both; as well as all the prefixes for the animation too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Cybercraft is correct. The external image in the snippet is not loading so running the snippet shows blank space, making it hard to visualize the answer. Below is an updated snippet using a local image.

```css
#stack {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=e5e58ae7df45);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: marquee 50s linear infinite;
  animation: marquee 50s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  from {
    left: 0
  }
  to {
    left: 100%
  }
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from {
    left: 0
  }
  to {
    left: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="stack" class="marquee"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of animating a div with css you could use the html marquee tag as shown here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Edit: iI have tested it in previous projects and it works in the newest versions of ie, chrome and firefox.

Comment: Straight from their website, at the top: **Non-standard
This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.**

Comment: never ever use <marquee> its Non-standard and deprecated!